# Assign JavaScript class (ES6) to jQuery selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, ecmascript-6

I am using a jQuery selector to select all elements with a particular class. I then proceed to create a new instance of a JavaScript Class for each selected element.

In later code I am selecting the jQuery element and need access to the class JavaScript class instance. How do you assign an instance of a class to a jQuery selected element?

Here is a code sample of what I want to achieve which doesn't work. Not sure of the correct way to do this:

```
let sampleElement = $('#sample-element');

// I want to assign the class instance to the element
sampleElement.sampleClass = new SampleClass(sampleElement);

// I want to call a function inside the class later
sampleElement.sampleClass.alertElementText();
```

Below is a more extensive code example of what I want to achieve:

**HTML**

```
<div id="sample-element-1" class="sample-element">
    This is some text!
</div>

<div id="sample-element-2" class="sample-element">
    This is some more text!
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
(function ($) {

    class SampleClass {

        constructor(element) {
            this.element = this;
        }

        alertElementText() {
            alert(this.element.text());
        }
    }


    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        let elements = $('.sample-element');

        elements.each(function() {

            new SampleClass($(this));

            // I need a way to assign the instance of the class 
            // to the element so I can access it later
            // Just unsure of the syntax   
        });

        // Here I want to access the class and call the alert function
        // The below lines won't work but it gives an indication of what I want to achieve
        $('#sample-element-1').alertElementText();
        $('#sample-element-2').alertElementText();
    });

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: [jquery data?](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: If you want to use `$('#sample-element-1').alertElementText();`, then you should assign the usual `$.fn.alertElementText = function(){ alert(this.text()); };`. Not create an ES6 class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a solution using [jQuery data](https://api.jquery.com/data/). Thanks to @jaromanda X for pointing me in the right direction.

Solution code:

```
let sampleElement = $('#sample-element');

// Here we assign the class instance to a unique key 'sampleClass'
sampleElement.data('sampleClass', new SampleClass(sampleElement));

// Here the class instance can be accessed and the function called
sampleElement.data('sampleClass').alertElementText();
```

Extended code with solution:

```
(function ($) {

    class SampleClass {

        constructor(element) {
            this.element = this;
        }

        alertElementText() {
            alert(this.element.text());
        }
    }


    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        let elements = $('.sample-element');

        elements.each(function() {
            // Here we assign the class instance to a unique key 'sampleClass'
            $(this).data('sampleClass', new SampleClass($(this))); 
        });

        // Now we can access the class instance when using other selectors
        $('#sample-element-1').data('sampleClass').alertElementText();
        $('#sample-element-2').data('sampleClass').alertElementText();
    });

}(jQuery));
```